# Checking two consecutive items in a list and count frequency

Tags: netlogo

I would like to check if two or more consecutive items in a list are the same and also to find the number of occurrences (frequency) of different items in a list. 
An example of input list would be

```
[ (item 1)  (item 2) (item 2) (item 4) (item 1) (item 2) ...]
```

What I would like to do is check if two or more same items are consecutive (e.g. item 2) and the frequency of each item (e.g. item 1 only two times, item 2 three times, item 4 only one).
For the frequency, I wrote

```
let counter map [ i -> frequency I my-list] (n-values length my-list [i -> i])
```

However, if I have  `[(item 211) (item 211) (item 187)]`, the counter returns me the values `[2 2 2]`.

For checking the items, I do not know how I could do it.

My list is built as follows:

```
 set selected people
          set color blue

          hatch-items 1 [
            hide-turtle
            set me selected

            set this-item self
            ask myself [
              set my-list fput this-item my-list
            ]
          ]
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Please provide example input data with desired output

Comment: Hi JenB, the input data is created by the code that generates the list (last code in the post). The output that Inwould expect would be the count of consecutive elements which are the same in the list and the frequency  of  each element in the list. I wrote it in the post. If it is still not clear, please let me know that I change the post to be more specific. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear. We don't care how you create the list, just what some of them look like (that's what I mean by example input). And you have only told us what your code is producing, not what you expected it to produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's an answer for how to check the frequencies of items in the list.**

There were three different problems with the code sample you posted.

- "item" is a reserved word. It is a command in the dictionary. Using it as a variable
  will have unpredictable results or not pass the editor's syntax checking.

  If you look closely in the editor, the word "item" is purple, not black, giving
  you this clue.  ( Thanks to JenB for pointing that out to me when I tried to use
  "e" as a variable name, which had the same problem. "e" is a command in NetLogo.)
- even if "item" was allowed as a breed type,  there is no built-in command named
  "frequency".   I couldn't find such a command in any of the usual extensions either.

  Where did you get this? Did you write your own "frequency" reporter? If so, 
  you need to post it here because that may be causing a problem as well.
- finally, in the command you wrote

```
let counter map [ i -> frequency I my-list] (n-values length my-list [i -> i])
```

the argument

```
(n-values length my-list [i -> i])
```

simply generates a list of sequential numbers, such as [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ].  You **don't** need such a list of index values into my-list, because "map" already implicitly goes down each item in the list already. What you **do** need is the actual list!   So all you need is this:

```
 let counter map [ i -> frequency I my-list]   my-list
```

Here is some working code that uses that new code and demonstrates that it works.

By the way, I found the **nifty code for a "frequency" reporter** under the name "occurrences" in the NetLogo User Dictionary as one of the examples of uses of the command "reduce".

```
globals [
my-list
]

;; item is a reserved word by the way. You need to use a different name.

to setup
  clear-all
  set my-list []

  ;; generate a sample my-list of agents to test this code
  create-turtles 3 [ set my-list fput self my-list]
  ask one-of turtles [ set my-list fput self my-list]
  ask one-of turtles [ set my-list fput self my-list]

  ;;set my-list [ 33 44 55 33 10 33 44 0 ]   ;; a simpler test

   reset-ticks

end

to go   
    show my-list  
    let counter map [ i -> frequency I my-list]   my-list   
    show counter 
  tick
end

 to-report frequency [x the-list]
  ;; this snippet of code is given as an example in the NetLogo Dictionary when defining "reduce"
  report reduce
    [ [occurrence-count next-item] -> ifelse-value (next-item = x) [occurrence-count + 1] [occurrence-count] ] (fput 0 the-list)
end
```

**Here's one way to check for at least one successive item in a list being the same as the previous item**.  I wrote this to print out the various steps to make it clearer to see how it works.  I'm sure someone could compact all of this into shorter and faster code, but, hey, this does the job, even if it uses a slow "foreach" test.

I took advantage of the fact tha "foreach" can compare each item in one list with the corresponding item in a second list

```
;; I would like to check if two or more consecutive items in a list are the same 

globals [
my-list
my-shifted-list
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set my-list []

  ;; generate a sample my-list of agents to test this code
  create-turtles 3 [ set my-list fput self my-list]
  ask one-of turtles [ set my-list fput self my-list]
  ask one-of turtles [ set my-list fput self my-list]

;   set my-list [ 333 4 5 333 333 3 333 4 0 ]   ;; a simpler test
;    set my-list [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]   ;; a simpler test

   show my-list


   reset-ticks

end

to go   
  show has-sequential-duplicates my-list
 end

to-report has-sequential-duplicates [ a-list ]

   ;; create a second list by shifting my-list one place to the left.
   ;; add a fake item to the end of the second list so it is the same length as my-list
   ;; so that the "foreach" command will work

   let templist remove-item 0 a-list
   set my-shifted-list lput -999 templist ;; add something that will never be in my-list
   show my-shifted-list  ;; this is one item shorted than a-list

   let dup-count 0
   ;; compare lists and count occurrences of identical items in the same place in each list
  (foreach my-list my-shifted-list [ [ a b ] -> 
       show ( word " Comparing " a " to " b )
       if ( a = b ) [ set dup-count (dup-count + 1) ] ])

    print word "count of duplicates: "  dup-count
    if-else ( dup-count > 0 ) [ report true ][ report false ]  
end
```